# How can I remove my errors in Alan AI project?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to build a voice assistant news app using Alan AI. In my code, I have used `newsapi.org API`. When I am trying to execute the code, it is showing me 2 errors. "`uncaught user exception`" and "`Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`". If possible someone pleas help on how to get rid off this error. Here's my code

```
intent('What does this app do?', 'What can I do here?', 
    reply('This is a news project.'));

const API_KEY = 'e1f728171ee54ccd861576421b6a9fbc';
let savedArticles = [];

intent('Give me the news from $(source* (.*))', (p) => {
    let NEWS_API_URL = `https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?apiKey=${API_KEY}`;

    if(p.source.value){
        NEWS_API_URL = `${NEWS_API_URL}&sources=${p.source.value.toLowerCase().split(" ").join('-')}`
    }
  
    api.request(NEWS_API_URL, (error, response, body) => {
        const  {articles}  = JSON.parse(body);
     
        if(!articles.length) {
            p.play('Sorry, please try searching for news from a different source');
            return;
        }
        
        savedArticles = articles;
        
        p.play({ command: 'newHeadlines', articles });
        p.play(`Here are the (latest|recent) ${p.source.value}.`);
    
    });
})
```

Comment: Only one place I could find the `length` from errors was `if(!articles.length)` part. Did you check the `body` from `api.request` ?

Comment: Like I followed the Alan AI documentation for getting an api request. Hence i used this

Answer (score 0):

I just recently got into this, the problem is that when you try to call the news from CNN or ESPN (words that doesn't have that "-" hyphen symbol) it says undefined,

Try calling BBC-news or ABC-news first then CNN or any other news feed, that's what worked for me

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Just you need to update api request method.
This code works perfectly, thanks.

```
let NEWS_API_URL = `https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?apiKey=${API_KEY}`;
if(p.source.value){
    NEWS_API_URL=`${NEWS_API_URL}&sources=${p.source.value.toLowerCase().split(" ").join('-')}`;
} 
api.request.get(NEWS_API_URL, (err, res, body) => {
    const {articles,totalResults} = JSON.parse(body);
    if(!totalResults){
        p.play('sorry, Please try searching news from different sources.!')
        return;
    } 
    p.play({command:'newHeadLines',articles});
    p.play(`Here are the total ${totalResults} latest news.`);
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the `UserAgentMissing error` therefore the articles are not set correctly. Here is the solution:

```js
const options = { 
              url: NEWS_API_URL, 
              headers: {'User-Agent': 'request'}
             };

 api.request(options, (error, response, body) => {...}
```